# What do I do with received packaged after credit card dispute won?

Tags: credit-card, dispute

I ordered a $500 winter jacket in August and was told it would be at my door by the end of October at the latest.  Between October and December I emailed the company 6-7 times asking for shipping updates and each time I was promised that it would be coming within the next two weeks.

By Christmas day, when it had still not arrived I lost faith that they were actually ever going to ship it.  This led to me opening a dispute with my credit card company since I was convinced the item would not be delivered.  I won my dispute and the $500 was credited to my account.

As of today (January 12) the package showed up in my mailbox... I am not sure what I am supposed to do, contact the credit card company, send the box back?  I don't really want the jacket any longer as it is mid January and I had to purchase another for this winter since they weren't shipping it!

Comment: Send the box back.

Answer (score 5):

The [US Postal Service](http://pe.usps.gov/text/dmm300/508.htm) will return the package to the sender free of charge if the package has not been opened. You can simply mark "Refused" across your address perhaps including the caption "return to sender".

Answer (score 4):

Contact the company, tell them it finally arrived and you want them to pay for return shipping and credit you with the return. A good store will do that. Get the return authorization number and the name and title of the person you spoke to.

Once you have that arranged, contact the bank and tell them what you have just agreed to, so they can make sure the credit is processed correctly.

Comment: There's no credit to be returned, the credit was returned before receiving the jacket.  Good call on getting them to pay for return shipping.  Good chance they won't want to do so, get that recorded some way if so.